# CommandLink ID not processing from VF to Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandlink

I have displayed a RecordSet of VF page with an option to delete the record like below,

```
<apex:page standardController="Container__c" extensions="searchDataController">

<apex:form>
<APEX:PAGEMessages id="error"></APEX:PAGEMessages>
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!getSearchResults}" reRender="mapofRecord">

       <apex:outputLabel >Gravic Account ID</apex:outputLabel> 
       <apex:inputText value="{!gravicID}" label="Gravic Account ID"/>
       <br></br>

       <apex:outputLabel >Customer PO Number</apex:outputLabel>
       <apex:inputText value="{!cusPoNumber}"/>
        <br></br>

       <apex:outputLabel >School Admin Name</apex:outputLabel>
       <apex:inputText value="{!schAdminName}"/>
        <br></br>

       <apex:outputLabel >Contact Name</apex:outputLabel>
       <apex:inputText value="{!cusName}"/>
        <br></br>

       <apex:outputLabel >School Admin Phone</apex:outputLabel>
       <apex:inputText value="{!schoolPhone}"/>
        <br></br>

       <apex:outputLabel >Dealer Rep Name</apex:outputLabel>
       <apex:inputText value="{!dealerName}"/>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>


    </apex:commandButton>


     <apex:outputPanel id="mapofRecord">

      <apex:outputText value="{!queryString}"></apex:outputText>

        <apex:pageBlock id="theResultBlock" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="ResultSection" columns="1" >
                <table width="100%" cellpadding ="1" cellspacing = "1" border="2px solid black">

                      <tr>
                          <td><b>Parameter</b></td>
                          <td><b>Value</b></td>
                          <td><b>Action</b></td>
                      </tr>

                    <apex:repeat value="{!searchRecordsMap}" var="fieldKey">
                        <tr>

                             <td>{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Parameter__c}</td>
                             <td>{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Value__c}</td>
                             <td>
                               <apex:commandLink onclick="setRowid();"  value="Delete" >
                                   <apex:param name="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}" assignTo="{!rowID}" value="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}"/>
                               </apex:commandLink>
                             </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </apex:repeat>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:actionFunction reRender="error,mapofRecord"   name="setRowid"  action="{!deleteRcd}" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:form>
```

But, I am not getting the record Id on my controller page function. Can anyone suggests where I am doing wrong.

```
public with sharing class searchDataController{

public Map<Id,Container__c> searchRecordsMap{ get; set; }

public string gravicID{get; set;}
public string cusPoNumber{get; set;}
public string schAdminName{get; set;}
public string cusName{get; set;}
public string schoolPhone{get; set;}
public string dealerName{get; set;}
public string gravicIDOutput{get; set;}

public string queryString{get; set;}


//defination for record deletei
public string rowID{get; set;}



public searchDataController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}


public void getSearchResults(){


    queryString = 'SELECT id,Parameter__c,Value__c FROM Container__c where';

    if(string.isNotEmpty(gravicID)) {

        queryString += ' (Parameter__c = \'' + 'Gravic Account ID' + '\' AND value__c Like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(gravicID)+'%\')';
    }


    if(string.isNotEmpty(cusPoNumber)) {

        //queryString = string.isNotEmpty(queryString) ? queryString +' AND ':' WHERE ';
        queryString += ' (Parameter__c = \'' + 'Customer PO Number' + '\' AND value__c Like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(cusPoNumber)+'\')';

    }

    if(string.isNotEmpty(schAdminName)) {

       // queryString = string.isNotEmpty(queryString) ? queryString +' AND ':' WHERE ';
        queryString += ' (Parameter__c = \'' + 'School Admin Name' + '\' AND value__c Like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(schAdminName)+'\')';

    }


    if(string.isNotEmpty(cusName)) {

      //  queryString = string.isNotEmpty(queryString) ? queryString +' AND ':' WHERE ';
        queryString += ' (Parameter__c = \'' + 'Contact Name' + '\' AND value__c Like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(cusName)+'\')'; 

    }



    if(string.isNotEmpty(schoolPhone)) {

       // queryString = string.isNotEmpty(queryString) ? queryString +' AND ':' WHERE ';
        queryString += ' (Parameter__c = \'' + 'School Admin Phone' + '\' AND value__c Like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(schoolPhone)+'\')';

    }



    if(string.isNotEmpty(dealerName)) {

        //queryString = string.isNotEmpty(queryString) ? queryString +' AND ':' WHERE ';
        queryString += ' (Parameter__c = \'' + 'Dealer Rep Name' + '\' AND value__c Like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(dealerName)+'\')';

    }

    List <Container__c> lstContainerDetail = new list<Container__c>();


    lstContainerDetail  = (List<Container__c>)Database.query(queryString);

    searchRecordsMap = new Map<Id, Container__c>(lstContainerDetail  );


   /* for(Container__c recordSet : lstContainerDetail) {

        //System.debug('Value of record is '+ recordSet.Value__c);
        searchRecordsMap.put(recordSet.Parameter__c, recordset);

    }*/


}

public PageReference deleteRcd() {

    if(rowID != NULL){
        System.debug('Id of the row to delete is' + rowID);
        Container__c delRecd = new Container__c();
        delRecd = [Select Parameter__c, Value__c, Id from Container__c where Id= : rowID];
        //delete delRecd;

        System.debug('delRecd ' + delRecd );

        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Row there');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);

        return null;
    }else{

        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Row id null');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        return null;
    }


}






}
```

Comment: Try having name and value attributes as same like `<apex:param name="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}" assignTo="{!rowID}" value="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}"/>`

Comment: Can you post the code from your apex class of how you initialise the rowId?

Comment: @VigneshwaranG : change did not worked.

Comment: @MarcZaharescu : Edited my original question to provide complete apex class code.

Comment: Provide your rerender which is present in action function to command link

Comment: @VigneshwaranG: Thought of sharing only the relevant code first. However, now added whole APex Class as well as VF page code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue of id not getting passed to controller is because of

```
<apex:commandLink onclick="setRowid();"  value="Delete" >
    <apex:param name="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}" assignTo="{!rowID}" value="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

and

```
<apex:actionFunction reRender="error,mapofRecord"   name="setRowid"  action="{!deleteRcd}" />
```

On click of `<apex:commandLink>`, `setRowid` will get called and invoke the `deleteRcd` action associated with it. But the value of `id` in `<apex:param>` will be passed on completion only.

So i would combine both these into

```
<apex:commandLink onclick="setRowid();"  value="Delete" reRender="error,mapofRecord" action="{!deleteRcd}">
    <apex:param name="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}" assignTo="{!rowID}" value="{!searchRecordsMap[fieldKey].Id}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

and remove the `<apex:actionFunction>` completely.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I was doing it earlier this way but that also did not worked well unfortunately.